# Project build error in xamarin studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

While building project an error is shown and build getting failed.

Error redirects to `axml` file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error :

```
C:\Users\Documents\Projects\\\Resources\layout\Main.axml(1,1): Error CS0116:
     A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods (CS0116) 
    (ABC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Build Action for the Main.axml file. It should be set to **Android Resource** but it sounds like it is set to **Compile**.

Right click the Main.axml file and use the Build Action menu to change this.